# Pipes vs Nested Function Calls

Tags: powershell, language-design, computer-science-theory

I recently was trained in Powershell and learned that you typically cannot return simple data types from complex powershell functions making the standard nested function call syntax of X=Foo(Bar(Hello("World"))) not possible/practical. The PowerShell solution is to use piping as in x= Hello "World" | Bar | Foo. I was wondering about the practical implications of this syntactical difference. Do we ultimately loose any useful language constructs by not being able to execute nested function calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use nested functions in Powershell.  You just don't call them using the same syntax you're used to:

```
Function Foo { "$($args[0])!" }
Function Bar { $args[0].ToUpper() }
Function Hello { "Hello $($args[0])" }

Foo (Bar (Hello "World"))

HELLO WORLD!
```

Comment: Yes but what are you passing to Bar and Foo? An object created by powershell holding all the values returned from any  function calls made in the preceding function. These Objects will differ in nature from implementation to implementation. Foo won't always get an object created by Bar, so how can you reliably reference it?

Comment: It's no different than passing arguments to any function.  The function will be designed to expect a particular object type for input.  If it gets an input type it's not designed for, it's going to throw an error. The pipeline will bind  a single property of an object to a parameter for you. If you pass the object as a parameter, you'll need to reference that property explicitly in the function, but that doesn't disallow nesting function calls.

Comment: Your functions are simple they consist of a single string and make no other function calls. I am specifically thinking of more complex functions that they themselves make multiple function calls but ultimately need to return a simple data type.

Comment: A powerhsell function can be written to expect any object type as a parameter argument, and return any object you can construct.  The return from one Powershell function can be used as the parameter argument for another Powershell function.  There's no reason you can't  nest them so that you have a chain of function calls, each one passing it's return as the argument to the next one.  If the last one needs to return a simple data type then that's an implementation issue, but there's no reason Powershell can't be made to do it.

Comment: As my post says your method isn't practical. Having to write most functions to only receive parameters created by another specific function is very restrictive.  It is much more useful to create functions that accept and return common data types that can be combined in as many ways as the programmer can imagine to fullfill his/her requirements.

Comment: Once you've written a function, how you pass it parameters arguments is irrelevant. Nothing in the function dictates that it's parameter values can only come from another function.